# ListView - Item selection disappears with scrolling

Tags: java, android

I'm newbie. For couple of days I'm trying to resolve this issue, but no luck. Any help ? Thanks in advance.

Below is the images,
[I selected few items and then scrolled up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4zFx.png)
[Once scrolled down selection disappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79Pmm.png)

Below the adapter class I implemented,

```
/**
 * Created by abcd on 27/1/17.
 */

public class ListItemAdapterTaxCheckBox extends BaseAdapter {

    //flag = 1 name/id
    //flag =2 //ID/Name
    public class HolderCheck
    {
        TextView tv;
        CheckBox ck;
    }

    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

    Tax[] result;
    Context context;
    Tax[] selections = null;
    String [] IDs = null;
    boolean bAllSel = false;

    Resources res = null;

    public ListItemAdapterTaxCheckBox(Activity mainActivity, Tax[] prgmNameList, Tax[] sel, Resources rs, String [] ids) {

        result=prgmNameList;
        context=mainActivity;
        selections = sel;


        if(selections==null)
        {
            selections = new Tax[1];
            selections[0] = new Tax();
        }

        IDs = ids;

        res = rs;

        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return result.length + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final HolderCheck holderCk = new HolderCheck();;
        View rowView = convertView;
        final int pos = position;

        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_check_box, null);
        holderCk.tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.code);
        holderCk.ck = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

        if(position==0) {
            holderCk.tv.setText(context.getString(R.string.all_text));
        }
        else {

            holderCk.tv.setText("" + result[position-1].m_TaxID + " - " + result[position-1].m_TaxName);
        }

        holderCk.tv.setTextSize(16);
        holderCk.tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (holderCk.ck.isChecked()) {
                    holderCk.tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    holderCk.ck.setChecked(false);

                    if(pos!=0)
                    {
                        if (IDs != null)
                            IDs[pos -1] = "0";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        bAllSel = false;
                    }

                } else {

                    holderCk.tv.setBackgroundColor(GetResourceColor.getColorWrapper(context, R.color.selHintColor));
                    holderCk.ck.setChecked(true);

                    if(pos!=0)
                    {
                        if (IDs != null)
                            IDs[pos -1] = "" + result[pos-1].m_TaxID;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        bAllSel = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        return rowView;
    }

    public String [] getIDs() {

        if(bAllSel)
            return null;
        else {
            ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < IDs.length; i++) {
                if (IDs[i].trim() != "0") {

                    arrayList.add(j, IDs[i].trim());

                    j = j + 1;

                    if (arrayList.size() == MySQLHelper.MAXITEMSLISTDELETE)
                        break;
                }
            }

            return arrayList.toArray(new String[arrayList.size()]);
        }
    }
}
```

Below the way I'm populating the ListView

```
//class member

Tax[] valuesTaxID = null;


//inside a method

//default
Tax[] tx = new Tax[1];
tx[0] = new Tax();

if (valuesTaxID != null) {
    listV.setAdapter(null);
    listV.setAdapter(new ListItemAdapterTaxCheckBox(ctx, valuesTaxID, tx, rs, Ids));
listV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: I don't really know what's happening in your code but i'll give you a rough idea of what you need to do.So when a user checks an item you would need to store a flag of some kind for each item that was checked so in your getView() method you would make a check saying if item.isChecked then holderCk.ck.setCheckd(true).

Comment: I would also suggest you use RecyclerView as its much more memory efficient and faster or use a viewholder pattern for your listview,a simple google search will help you know what that is.Follow this page it really helps https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListView will create and destroy views when you scroll. Your code is changing a checkbox when a view is clicked, but you store that info nowhere else, you scroll, ListView destroys the view when you scroll, and there you lost the status of the view.

You want to store the "checked" state of the view somewhere. Could be an ArrayList with states, could be a tag attached to the ViewHolders, ... just store it somewhere.

Comment: my bad! How did I miss this!